# Can anyone see why my log file keeps ending up empty here?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing some code to make a small UDS server for an assignment. The client will make a specific series of connections to the server carrying certain messages. Basically if those messages appear in our log file in order then we are all set. But my log file is coming up completely blank every time I run, and I'm not sure I see why.

Here is my code:

```
// forward declarations
int error_msg( char * msg );
int usage( char name[] );

// a function to be executed by each thread
void * recv_log_msgs( void * arg );

// globals
FILE * log_fd; // opened by main() but accessible by each thread
typedef struct sockaddr SA;

void * recv_log_msgs( void * arg ) //Thread Routine
{
    // loops to receive messages from a client;
    // when the connection is closed by the client,
    // close the socket
    int clientfd = *((int *)arg);
    char buffer[1500];
    memset(buffer, 0, 1500);
    int currentPos = 0;
    int bytesRec;
    int recvng = 1;

    while(recvng){
        bytesRec = recv(clientfd, buffer, 1500-currentPos, 0);
        currentPos += bytesRec;
        if(buffer[currentPos - 1] == '\n')
            recvng = 0;
    }

    fprintf(log_fd, "LOGGER %d %s", clientfd, buffer);
    close(clientfd);
    return NULL;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 3 )
        return usage( argv[0] );

    log_fd = fopen(argv[1], "a");

    // create a server socket
    // domain (i.e., family) is AF_UNIX
    // type is SOCK_STREAM

    socklen_t clientLength = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
    struct sockaddr_un clientAddr;
    clientAddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(clientAddr.sun_path, argv[2]);

    pthread_t tid;

    int listenfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);     

    // unlink the UDS path)
    unlink(argv[2]);

    // bind the server socket
    bind(listenfd, (SA *)&clientAddr, clientLength);    

    // listen
    listen(listenfd, 1024);
    // loop to wait for connections;
    // as each connection is accepted,
    // launch a new thread that calls
    // recv_log_msgs(), which receives
    // messages and writes them to the log file
    while(1){
        printf( "Waiting for a connection on UDS path %s...\n", argv[2] );
        int * clientfdp = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *clientfdp = accept(listenfd, (SA *) &clientAddr, &clientLength);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, recv_log_msgs, clientfdp);
        printf("%d",errno);
        return 0;
    }

    // when the loop ends, close the listening socket
    close(listenfd);        

    // close the log file
    fclose(log_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

The writing to the log occurs in the top function, `recv_log_msgs`. I'm newish to C and I often get tripped up by specifics on how files are handled, or think of memory arrays on too high of a level, stuff like that. I don't really see why *nothing* should be writing, given my code. Am I even trying to "read" the data properly, by calling `recv()` on the client file descriptor? Am I using buffers correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: @MohitJain That was of course my first instinct, and I tried. But the behavior of the client that makes all of the calls to connect is in a executable that was given to us with the assignment. So I'm not exactly sure how to debug that. When I try, it just always steps right through to the end, and says it has no line numbers to show.

Comment: You can try to put a print in the while loop to see if and how bytesRec is filled up. Also, you should check the return value of recv.

Comment: Your code is using `fprintf(log_fd, ....)` from multiple threads.   Those calls need to be synchronised (e.g. using a mutex).

Comment: @Peter But isn't that what `join` is for

Comment: No it is not.  `join()` causes one thread to wait for completion of another.   It doesn't make two threads that are concurrently accessing the same resource (`log_fd` in your case) do so in a coherent/synchronised/predictable manner.

Comment: @Peter How would I go about extending what I have to work in the mutlithreaded case? I've actually just fixed it and it is working partially. Would the mutex go in the while loop in `main`?

Comment: Initialise one mutex in `main()`.   Every (and I mean every) section of code that accesses `log_fd` needs to grab that mutex, do their thing(s) to `log_fd`, and then release the mutex.   The result will be only one thread writing to `log_fd` (and its buffers) at any point in time.   The initialisation of the mutex happens only once in the entire program.   The grabbing and the release happens EVERY time code does something with `log_fd`.

Comment: I've added it, but I see no difference. What I should see is three different outputs from each of three threads, but I only see one output from each.

Answer (score 0):

`if(buffer[currentPos - 1] == '\n')` that can't work. Whether you find newlines or not depends on the chunk sizes you get.

The loop never breaks. You need to search *all* chars in the chunk that you have received. Right now this is checking just one char, and an arbitrarily chosen one at that.

Comment: So what is the easiest way to check ever char in a buffer for a specified char?

Comment: Ideally, you find a standard library function to search the buffer for a newline. If that's not available you write a loop to inspect each char.

Comment: The entire `while(recvng)` loop is broken.  All `recv` calls overwrite the data read from earlier calls.

Comment: @AndrewHenle right, I didn't even validate this. Probably he should write data out as soon as it is received. That saves him from the pointer/index calculation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I can't see why. How can I fix that? I think that's my main problem.

Comment: @jphollowed `bytesRec = recv(clientfd, buffer, 1500-currentPos, 0);` reads data to the same location in `buffer`.  Whatever was there from any previous call is overwritten.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sure but not in my case, because I know that the number of bytes before a '\n' will never be anywhere near 1500. Its like 30.

Comment: The 2nd read overwrites the data of the first. Do you see why that happens? You always pass `buffer` to `read`. Do you understand the point of this answer? Maybe you should start fixing the code and posting a new version to move this question along.